# Can't open a resampled image on Matlab with C++

Tags: c++, image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have a C++ code written using OpenCv which works well on my images. But, because the code takes too long to run, I decided to change each image's dimensions and save in a folder. The part of the code written in Matlab where I resample the images is the following:

```
    %read image  
    image=imread(char(image_name));
    %The image will become 4 times smaller
    img_resized=imresize(image,0.25);  
    %save the image with the same name, but now it is smaller
    C = regexp(char(image_name),'/','split');
    imwrite(img_resized, [name_folder '/' char(C(end))]);
```

What is really strange is, when I run the C++ code on these resized images I get segmentation fault error. When I run on the original images the code works well.

That's the error returned when I run the code on the resized images. Here, beach_wood_copy_r8.png is the resized image

```
  ./zernike beach_wood_copy_r8.png beach_wood_gt_r8.png resu.png
  Reading Images
  Calculating Zernike
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And there is the part of the C++ source code where the error happens:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int r, c, nDegree, nBlockSize;
  printf("Reading Images\n");
  BYTE** pSrc = getImage(argv[1], r, c);
  BYTE** pGround = getImage(argv[2], r, c);
  set<pair<int, int>, LessFunctionClass> matchedIndex;
  time_t start_time, end_time, prog_time;   

  start_time = time(NULL);

  nDegree = 6;
  nBlockSize = 24;
  printf("Calculating Zernike\n");
  //error happens here
  calculateZernike(pSrc, r, c, nDegree, nBlockSize);
  printf("Zernike calculated\n");
```

**EDIT:** The function getImage is in the following lines:

```
BYTE** getImage(char* fName, int& r, int& c){

IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(fName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
int i, j;
BYTE **pSrc;

c = img->width;
r = img->height;

pSrc = new BYTE*[r];

for(i=0; i<r; i++){
    pSrc[i] = new BYTE[c];
}


for(i=0; i<r; i++){
    for(j=0; j<c; j++){
        pSrc[i][j] = img->imageData[i*c + j];
    }
}
cvReleaseImage( &img);
return pSrc;
}
```

**EDIT 2** Here is where the source code calculates the zernike moments:

```
void calculateZernike(BYTE **p_block, int r, int c, int degree, int blockSize)
{

int i, j, k, l, m, n, numDegree;
double pi;
pi = acos(-1.0);

COMPLEX ***p_Vnm = getZernikePolynomial(blockSize, degree);
numDegree = 0;
for(i=0; i<degree; i++){
    numDegree += (i/2+1);
}

for(i=0; i<c-blockSize+1; i=i+1){
    for(j=0; j<r-blockSize+1; j=j+1){
        BlockInfo zResult;
        zResult.m_x = i;
        zResult.m_y = j;

        int zDegree = 0;
        for(n=0; n<degree; n++){
            for(m=0; m<=n; m++){
                if( (n-m)%2 == 0 ){
                    COMPLEX sumValue;
                    sumValue.r = 0;
                    sumValue.j = 0; 

                    for(k=0; k<blockSize; k++){
                        for(l=0; l<blockSize; l++){
                            sumValue.r += p_Vnm[zDegree][k][l].r * p_block[j+k][i+l];
                            sumValue.j += p_Vnm[zDegree][k][l].j * p_block[j+k][i+l];
                        }
                    }
                    sumValue.j *= (n+1)/pi;
                    sumValue.r *= (n+1)/pi;

                    double tempMag, tempPhase;
                    tempMag = sqrt(sumValue.j*sumValue.j + sumValue.r*sumValue.r);
                    tempPhase = atan2(sumValue.r, sumValue.j);
                    sumValue.r = tempMag;
                    sumValue.j = tempPhase;



                    zResult.ZMM.push_back(sumValue);
                    zDegree++;
                }
            }
        }

        blockZMMs.push_back(zResult);

    }
}



for (i=0; i<numDegree; i++){
    for(j=0; j<blockSize; j++){
        delete [] p_Vnm[i][j];
    }
    delete [] p_Vnm[i];
}
delete p_Vnm;

return ;
```

}

I think C++ can't open the resized images. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: "C++ can't open resized images" is nonsense.  My gut feeling is that you are accessing locations that are out of bounds in the images.  Did you make sure to change `r` and `c` after you resized the images?  Are `r` and `c` hard coded in your C++ program?  I don't see `r` and `c` being read in or set anywhere, so I'm assuming this is done outside of `main`.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for your answer, r anc c receives the image width and height respectively, see my edit. The image is already resized when I run the code, I just point where the image is.

Comment: Where is `r` and `c` being received?  I don't see an edit.

Comment: Are `nDegree` and `nBlockSize` valid for the smaller images?

Comment: @GeoffHayes I tried the same for another images of other databases and nBlocksize worked well without problems. Do you think I should change it?

Comment: @rayryeng can you see it now?

Comment: @mad - I see it.  It looks like your error isn't happening there.  Do you have provisions in your Zernike calculations to ensure that you're not accessing pixels out of bounds?  Can you show us your Zernike moments code?

Comment: @rayryeng can you see now the zernike's moment code?

Comment: @mad - what are the values of `r` and `c` for the reduced images?  Is `r` less than `nBlockSize`?  (Or `c` for that matter…)

Comment: @GeoffHayes - r and c are the image's width and height. I resized the images, so r and c are the resized images height and width. The images are 4 times smaller, but the images dimensions are always greater than nBlockSize

Comment: @mad - The first two `for` loops with indices `i` and `j` seem suspicious. Are you sure it should be `i<c-blockSize+1`, `j<r-blockSize+1`? Should the `+1` be removed?

Comment: beach_wood_copy_r8.png on the example has 816 pixels width and 612 pixels height

Comment: Also, did you check to see whether your two inner for loops are accessing pixels out of bounds? It doesn't look like you are

Comment: @rayryeng even if I remove +1 the error continues. Anyway, this source code is not mine but it worked with other resized images.

Comment: @mad - what assumptions are there on `zDegree`?  Is it less than or equal to `degree`?  Was just curios as it is used in `p_Vnm[zDegree][k][l]` so wondered how the two might be related and what guarantees there were that `zDegree` never exceeded the first dimension of `p_Vnm`.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the two inner `for` loops are trying to access pixels out of bounds.  It probably has worked up until now because you haven't had an instance where the selected block size is trying to go out of bounds in the image.  Try placing this within the inner most `for` loop (`l = 0 ...`) before doing any calculations:  `if (j+k < 0 || j+k >= r || i+l < 0 || i+l >= c) continue;`

Comment: @mad - If your image is 816 x 612 originally, using a block size of 24 will evenly fit each of these dimensions.  When you resize the image down by 25%, you get 204 x 153.  This **does not** fit evenly with a block size of 24, hence you are getting out of bounds errors.

Comment: @rayryeng sorry, the original image dimensions is 3264x2448, 816x 612 are the dimensions of the image resized.

Comment: @mad - Geoff Hayes is right.  Where is `zDegree` declared?  Also, try that suggestion I made above within the `for` loop with index `l`.  Does it still happen?

Comment: @rayryeng I think your solution worked, I am just waiting for the program to finish. The error is not happening anymore but it is still processing

Comment: @mad - Let me know what happens.  If it does work, may I write an answer for you to accept?

Comment: @rayryeng Of course! write it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we have discussed in the comments, inside the Zernike moments calculation code, the two inner most `for` loops are trying to access pixels that are out of bounds in the image.  In order to prevent this, try writing the following `if` statement before you do any calculations:

```
for (k = 0; k < blockSize; k++) {
     for (l = 0; l < blockSize; l++) {
          // Change here
          if (j+k < 0 || j+k >= r || i+l < 0 || i+l >= c) 
             continue;

          sumValue.r += p_Vnm[zDegree][k][l].r * p_block[j+k][i+l];
          sumValue.j += p_Vnm[zDegree][k][l].j * p_block[j+k][i+l];
     }
}
```

The `if` statement within the `for` loop should prevent accessing pixels that are outside the dimensions of the image.  This safeguard was not here before in your code.

Comment: @mad - Cool!  Was this the reason why you kept getting segmentation faults?